# Javascript in GSP files broken in Grails 3

Tags: javascript, forms, grails, gsp

I've undertaken the arduous process of upgrading a project from Grails 2 to Grails 3. I've survived mostly intact so far, but I've hit a pretty mystifying roadblock: the Javascript that worked perfectly on the Grails 2 version appears to be completely ignored in the Grails 3 version.

Example: I have a page with a single field that is required to be filled out before the form can be submitted. Below is the code for the whole page - the javascript is at the end:

```
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="main">
</head>
<body>
    <g:render template="worksheet/nav"/>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="errors" class="small alert alert-error" style="display:none"></div>
            <br/>
            <g:form class="form-horizontal" url="[action:'worksheet']" id="form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">    
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="control-group formSep">
                        <label class="control-label" for="moveType">
                            Client *
                        </label>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <g:select name="client" class="input-medium" from="${clients}" noSelection="['':'']" value="${map.client?.name}"/>    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="btn-toolbar">
                        <g:hiddenField name="_eventId" value="next"/>
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            <g:link event="skip" class="btn btn-large">Skip</g:link>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Next</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<g:javascript>
$("#form").on('submit', function() {
    $('#errors').html('');
    $('#errors').hide();
});
$("#form").validate({
    onfocusout: false,
    onkeyup: false,
    onclick: false,
    rules: {
        client: "required"
    },
    messages: {
        client: "Please select a client"
    },
    errorElement: "div",
    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        $('#errors').append(error);
        $('#errors').show();
    }
});
```

In Grails 2, this works as expected - the page will verify a selection has been made before submitting the form. But in Grails 3, nada - the form gets submitted and the system moves on to the next page even if the user hasn't picked anything. I checked the source code after compiling and the JS is there, so I'm not sure why it's getting ignored. Any ideas?

Some additional context: I'm also upgrading JQuery from 1.8.0 to 2.2.0, and Bootstrap from 2.0.x to 3.3.6.

Comment: Your script seems OK, I think you forgot the </g:javascript> on stackoverflow (if not, this is the problem). Otherwise, make sure that JQuery is imported **before** your script (when migrating from Grails 2 to Grails 3, you may have changed the order, or removed it completly). If everything is OK, then open the browser console (it's often CTRL MAJ I) and check if there if there isn't any errors on the javascript / console web.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The Javascript block is closed properly in the code (I'm not sure why SO isn't showing it) and JQuery is the first import, so I'm good there. I noticed an error in the Javascript console, which I was able to fix with an import. That did fix another JS issue, but the inline JS on this page is still being ignored. So the system is being choosy about which JS to read? Doesn't make sense.

Some additional context: I'm also upgrading JQuery from 1.8.0 to 2.2.0, and Bootstrap from 2.0.x to 3.3.6.

Comment: What's your JQuery plugin for Form Validating ? I think the problem is with the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` on your plugin : you changed the JQuery version and probably something that worked with the previous version isn't working anymore.

Comment: Yep, that's what it was - I'm using the jQuery validation plugin v1.10.0, which is years old. The current version is 1.15.1, which I plan on testing out later - I'm trying to upgrade too many things at once and need to finish with Grails before working on jQuery and Bootstrap.